# In a deck of $52$ cards, how many ways can the first card be a club, the second an ace and the third a diamond?

Tags: combinatorics

> In a deck of $52$ cards how many ways can the first card be a club the second an ace and the third a diamond?

I am getting $65$ as my answer; $13 \cdot 3 + 13 \cdot 2$.  Is this correct?

Comment: Seems far too small.  Even if you require that the ace be neither $\clubsuit$ nor $\diamondsuit$ you get $13\times 2\times 13$ which is a lot greater than $65$.

Comment: there's more than one case to consider is the first card the ace of clubs or not ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  You can consider cases.

1. $A\clubsuit, \color{red}{A\diamondsuit}$, a diamond other than $\color{red}{A\diamondsuit}$
2. $A\clubsuit$, $\color{red}{A\heartsuit}$ or $A\spadesuit$, a diamond
3. a club other than $A\clubsuit$, $\color{red}{A\diamondsuit}$, a diamond other than $\color{red}{A\diamondsuit}$
4. a club other than $A\clubsuit$, an ace other than $\color{red}{A\diamondsuit}$, a diamond

Since these cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, you can find the total by adding the four cases.

Comment: 780???  1*1*12+1*1*1+12*1*12+12*4*13???

Comment: @LindaH  Not quite.  Your calculations for the first and third cases are correct.  $A\clubsuit$, $\color{red}{A\heartsuit}$ or $A\spadesuit$, a diamond: $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 13$.  A club other than $A\clubsuit$, an ace other than $\color{red}{A\diamondsuit}$, a diamond:  $12 \cdot 3 \cdot 13$.  Hence, we obtain $$1 \cdot 1 \cdot 12 + 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 13 + 12 \cdot 1 \cdot 12 + 12 \cdot 3 \cdot 13 = 12 + 26 + 144 + 468 = 650$$

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where your number comes from, but it is much too small.

There are $13$ choices for the club, $13$ for the diamond, and $4$ for the ace. So there would be $13\times4\times 13$ different options, except that some of these options are impossible, either because they have the first two cards both being the ace of clubs or because they have the second and third cards both being the ace of diamonds. Can you work out how many options are left when you remove these impossible ones?

Comment: 13*13*2 the 2 is for the 2 aces left (heart and spade) 338, if this correct?

Comment: No, there are other possibilities where the second card is the ace of clubs ($12\times 13$ ways, since the first card can be any of the $12$ other clubs and the third any diamond) or when the second card is the ace of diamonds ($13\times 12$).

Comment: I'm not following what you mean, can you elaborate?